# How to use properly Timer Object?

Tags: c#, asp.net, timer

I have this code behind in asp.net page:

```
    protected void LoadFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
               Timer myTimer = new Timer();
               myTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler( RemoveFile );
               myTimer.Interval = 60000;
               myTimer.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
    }

    private void RemoveFile(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
            string path = UniquePath();
            File.Delete(path);
    }
```

When LoadFile event handler fired the RemoveFile function fired after 60 sec(as defined in this row myTimer.Interval = 60000), if LoadFile fired again after 40 seconds the RemoveFile will fire in 20 seconds.

My question is how to make the `RemoveFile` function to be activated after 60 seconds from last call of the `LoadFile` event hanlder?

Comment: `if LoadFile fired again after 40 seconds the RemoveFile will fire in 20 seconds.` - Do you mean the `RemoveFile` will be called twice at that point? (One minute after the first call, 20 seconds after the second)? Or it will be called only once?.

Comment: Please don't ever code `catch (Exception)`, let alone `catch (Exception) { }`. That is a bad practice that hides bugs.

Comment: @Rob It will called only once

Comment: @Enigmativity Reminds me of the good old days approach of `ON ERROR RESUME NEXT`

Comment: Could you not touch the filestamp and have a separate request which runs and removes the file after 60 seconds of the file not being updated?

Comment: Side note: Using Timers in ASP.Net is generally asking for trouble - there is no guarantees that it will ever happen... You may be better off coming up with polling solution external to the site. I'd personally have daily/hourly cleanup script - which would be fine as access to files controlled by proper authentication/timing code in the site anyway  so removing files later is ok (unless there is legal requirement otherwise which is unlikely).

Answer (score 0):

May be you could use 
`myTimer.Stop();` just after `Timer myTimer = new Timer();`

Answer (score 0):

I would use Microsoft's Reactive Extensions (NuGet "Rx-Main") for this. The code becomes:

```
private SerialDisposable _serialDisposable = new SerialDisposable();

protected void LoadFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _serialDisposable.Disposable =
        Observable
            .Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60.0))
            .Subscribe(n =>
            {
                string path = UniquePath();
                File.Delete(path)
            });
}
```

Now, observables are like events and calling `.Subscribe` is like attaching to an event. The `.Subscribe` call returns an `IDisposable` which you can use to detach from the observable by calling `.Dispose()`. The `SerialDisposable` object is a special disposable class provided by Rx that lets you assign new disposables and automatically dispose any previously assigned disposables. This automatically resets the timer every time `LoadFile` is run.

This is just one use of Rx - it has so many more uses and is very powerful and worth learning.

Comment: But LoadFile is asp.net event handler in asp.net. So if I create serialDisposable as class variable it will recreated in each postback call.

Comment: @Michael You can put it in a session variable. Or in a static collection and load/create the `_serialDisposable` based on your logic.